# Analyze baseball pitchers in R

Tags: r

I want to solve  the following task:

Name every pitcher in baseball history who has accumulated at least 300 wins ( W ) and at least 3,000 strikeouts ( SO ).

(Hint: Use Team data in Lahman package)

So far I tried

```
library(Lahman)
Teams  %>% filter(W >= 300 & SO >= 3000) %>% select(name, W, SO)
```

Problem 1.But that gives me Zero Rows back and doesnt even include the pitcher aswell.

Problem 2.I started noticing this function within Lahman called : "playerinfo(xxx)" maybe thats how I find the pitchers name out

Help me please solve this 2 problems

Comment: Did you check the max value of W ?

Comment: The hint doesn't make sense. It must be a typo. The `Teams` table doesn't contain information about individual pitchers. The dataset `Pitching` must be intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @John Coleman says, the df `Teams` doesn't contain player level info. That is found in `Pitching`. But you had almost done the right thing. Remember to group by the playerID, since the data spans different seasons and then left join with the People df to get their name.

```
Lahman::Pitching %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(playerID) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(W = sum(W), SO = sum(SO)) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(W >= 300 & SO >= 3000) %>%
    dplyr::left_join(Lahman::People) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(name = stringr::str_c(nameGiven, nameLast)) %>%
    dplyr::pull(name)
```

```
 [1] "Steven NormanCarlton" "William RogerClemens" "Randall DavidJohnson" "Walter PerryJohnson"  "Gregory AlanMaddux"   "Philip HenryNiekro"  
 [7] "Gaylord JacksonPerry" "Lynn NolanRyan"       "George ThomasSeaver"  "Donald HowardSutton"
```